# Syntax highlight in SublimeText 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting

How do I get Sublime Text 2 to highlight syntax of a language? I tried everything I could find but none of that bore any fruit. Thanks

Comment: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html

Answer (score 0):

Sublime usually recognizes the file's syntax based on it's file extension:

- Try saving it with an appropriate extension - e.g. for PHP highlighting save it as yourfilename.php

If this doesn't work, you can manually set the syntax for the file:

- In the application menu, go to View > Syntax and select the desired highlighting mode.